# How can I Generate a URL for a text file without a specific website/server?

Tags: python, wordpress, url

Here's what I want to do: Generate a url that I can put in my wordpress blog which will let users view a big text file. I don't know how I can generate this url. I was inspired by websites like Flickr which generate urls for images and was hoping there is a corollary for just text files.

I was taking the MITx 6.00.1x Python course, and one assignment had us refer to a text file that the professor had uploaded onto his course site. So the text file has a url: 
https://courses.edx.org/c4x/MITx/6.00.1x_5/asset/words.txt

Not sure if this url is available to non members.

Is there a way I can upload this file to a universal url that anyone can access for free?

Kind regards,

Spencer

Comment: There are many services that host text files for free, such as Pastebin and GitHub's Gist.

Comment: dropbox, google docs and numerous others

Answer (score 0):

The way this works is actually supplying the path to the text file (in this case words.txt) on the web server. When you click that link, you're going from the root through several directories and accessing that file.

If you have access to the actual files on your wordpress blog, you can add a text file there and then give people the path to that file.

Otherwise, use a service such as Pastebin to provide the text file.